# malformed json (js to php)

Tags: javascript, json

I'm processing a form and iframe. The resulting json is the following:

```
{"title":"form 01", "library_id":1, "parameters":{"direction":"EsteOeste"}}
```

I send it via jquery ajax post to php and it's giving me an error (json_last_error):

JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX

var_dump before json_decode:

```
{\"title\":\"form 01\", \"library_id\":1, \"parameters\":{\"direction\":\"EsteOeste\"}}
```

How can I correct it?

Comment: You are double-encoding your JSON. Drop the call to `JSON.stringify()`.

Comment: @Tomalak: if it was double-encoded, there'd be an extra set of quotes to make it a JS string. this is probably php magic_quotes or some other stupid auto-escape system mangling the text.

Comment: @MarcB I don't think so. The output of `var_dump` pretty clearly shows a double-encoded JSON string. My crystal ball tells me the OP does `$.ajax({contentType: "application/json", data: JSON.stringify(foo), ...})` when `$.ajax({contentType: "application/json", data: foo, ...})` would be correct.

Comment: json encode an object, you get a string . json encode that string, you'll get a string-in-string, e.g. `"{\"foo\":\"bar\"}"`. note the outer quotes. there are no outer quotes in OP's sample, therefore it's not a json_encoded string. it's a json-encoded object that's been mangled by magic_quotes.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this, it was indeed at the php side. After stripping slashes it worked as intended.